# How Can I Control Which Ciphers Can Be Used When Accessing An Azure-Hosted Website?

Tags: azure, encryption, certificate

I have a site deployed on Azure and I'd like to prevent certain ciphers from being used when accessing the site. We ran a tool against the site to see which ciphers could interact with the site. We came back with this:

[image: Ciphers]

I'd like to shut off access from any ciphers in TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1.

I'd also like to shut off access from any ciphers in TLS 1.2 that are using 128-bit encryption.

Doing some research, I came across this in the Azure Portal:

[image: Azure]

I went to my App Service, clicked the SSL settings and clicked 1.2. That should, in theory, prevent access from people using anything below TLS 1.2, correct? It *appears* to have no effect. I went to https://www.ssllabs.com and typed in my site's URL. Here are the results:

[image: Protocols]

This seems to be indicating that nothing changed? Does this feature not work? Is there something else I must do? Is there a way to do this programmatically (C#.NET)? Do I have to change the certificate in any way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The TLS setting works fine on my side:https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywxx4.png

Comment: Huh... I wonder if it's because this site was created a while ago. Probably late 2017. I know this setting was having issues as recently as a few weeks ago.